# Jquery in javascript function require two clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick, double-click

I wrote a simpe inline edit using jquery. The plugin work very well, but i have a problem when i call the script within a javascript function, it require 2 click to activate the plugin. Does anyone know a way to solve this issue.. i want it in one click! Thanks in advance.

```
<a onclick="update(1)"> Let's update<a/>

  function update(id)
  {
  $("#edit" + id).kb_edit();   
  }
```

Comment: Can you give more context? Like perhaps the `kb_edit()` process?

Comment: Which browser are you experiencing the issue in?

Comment: Is this your plugin? The problem is most likely in there, so you'd need to provide the code. Also, you have `<a/>` instead of `</a>`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted above (other than the typo @patrick noted). See http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/sZ9KQ/ - a single click triggers the handler without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the functionality in the plugin requires the click event handler that you're setting up inside, then that means it won't be set up until you run `.kb_edit()`.

So the first click runs `.kb_edit()`, which sets up the `click` handler.

Then the second click actually gets to trigger whatever was set up by the first click.

Answer (score 0):

well for starters you could clean it up a little by NOT using the onclick...

```
<a id="myAnchor">Let's update</a>

$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#myAnchor").click(function(){
        ///put your update code here including the kb_edit code
   });
});
```

or if you have a series of this you can use `<a class="myAnchor">...</a>` and change the jquery selector:

```
   $(".myAnchor").click(function(){
```

Comment: Oh guys !! sorry about this i did a dump mistake !! In my plugin there is a .click function..  so it's why it takes two clicks to be fired. Thanks a lot !!