# Jquery onclick event requires two clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

On click, I want to hide/show some html code(which is obtained via a GET request to another page). It works but the problem is that it requires two clicks instead of one.

There is one other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526906/jquery-in-javascript-function-require-two-clicks) that seems related but I am not able to understand that.

```
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".quote-toggle").click( function(event) {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.get( $(this).attr('href'), function(msg) {
                if($("#toggler_" + id).html()=='show') {
                    $("#" + id).html(msg);
                    $("#toggler_" + id).html('hide'); 
                  }
                else {
                    $("#" + id).html('');
                    $("#toggler_" + id).html('show'); 
                 }
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
     });
   </script>
```

This is my first time with jquery/javascript. Any explanation or suggestions for the code would be much appreciated.
[Edit]
jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KCLf5/1/

Comment: can we see all the markup? maybe create a jsfiddle?

Comment: I would put event.preventdefault as the first line in the block

Comment: @pimvdb not sure if it matters, that's why I said 'I would'... maybe the normal behavior happens before you prevent it or something. Just a wild guess without looking at the HTML

Comment: @AndyL, added the jsfiddle link. Though it is not functioning properly on jsfiddle, you'll be able to see all the markups.

Comment: The js fiddle seems to work fine with one click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had to guess, `$("#toggler_" + id)`'s html is not set to `show`. So the first click will set it to show and the second will load the data.

Make sure that the toggler has the correct html when the page loads

Comment: Earlier, it was 'show '. Forgot to trail spaces. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

1. First of all - you shouldn't do get request on hide element.
2. Second - event.preventDefault should be at the start of event. It
   will save you from unexcepted behaviour on javascript errors.

Here is code, that uses these 2 recomendations:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".quote-toggle").click( function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        if($("#" + id).html()=='') {
            $.get(url, function(msg) {
                $("#" + id).html(msg);
                $("#toggler_" + id).html('hide'); 
            });
         } else {
            $("#" + id).html('');
            $("#toggler_" + id).html('show'); 
         }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For two days I wrestled with having the "2-clicks-required-to-load-first-external-html" problem.

After one would load, requiring 2 clicks, the rest would behave and load on 1 click.

I easily solved this by creating a blank html file, and placing its load command on the line following "(document).ready". Nothing else I tried from forums would work for me, but this did on the very first try.

I had noticed that the JS file wanted one html file loaded before it would load any of the others, so I gave it one to load automatically. Simple fix and works like a charm!